# Displaying base64 format pdf as a thumbnail in vuejs2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Need to display base64 format pdf in vuejs2 as a thumbnail and on clicking that thumbnail the entire pdf should be viewed in new tab.
I just made use of vue-pdf lib and i can display pdf as thumnails as using vue-pdf it gives look and fill as thumbnail then on click of that thumnail i just use window.open(encodeURI(src)) wrapped into iframe which works fine for small size pdf but for large size pdf the pdf doesn't get viewed  in new tab.

Comment: I am not expert in this brt I find difficult to understand the question at some points. Can you clarify? Is it possible to provide an example?

Comment: @DimitriosZacharatos i have created custom component for the same.Thanks for your response :D

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me...

HTML:

```html
<div :src="'data:application/pdf;base64,'+doc">

</div>
PS: you can use <iframe></iframe> instead of div
JS:
<script>
 data():{
   doc: 'base64 format here'
 }
</script>
```